# Insufficient Privileges after creating Pluggable Database

Tags: permissions, oracle-18c

I have to confess I have no idea about this pluggable database thing. I have experience in PostgresSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, but Oracle has me defeated.

I have Oracle 18c running in a Docker image. I want to create a pluggable database called `bookshop`. Following some instructions, I ran the following:

```sql
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE bookshop ADMIN USER pdb_adm IDENTIFIED BY Oradoc_db1
    file_name_convert=('/opt/oracle/oradata/XE/pdbseed','/opt/oracle/oradata/XE/BOOKSHOP');
```

Next in the instructions, I run:

```sql
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE xepdb2 OPEN READ WRITE;
```

except that I can’t. I get the message:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.

I then try:

```sql
DROP PLUGGABLE DATABASE bookshop;
```

and I get the same message.

When I try:

```sql
SELECT vp.name, vp.open_mode
FROM v$pdbs vp;
```

I get

| NAME | OPEN_MODE |
| --- | --- |
| PDB$SEED | READ ONLY |
| XEPDB1 | READ WRITE |
| XEPDB2 | READ WRITE |
| BOOKSHOP | MOUNTED |

And finally, when I try to work out who I am:

```sql
SELECT user FROM dual;
```

I get `SYSTEM`.

At this point I have no idea how to get control over this pluggable database. Do I need to switch to another user? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try connecting to your container database as SYS instead of SYSTEM. SYSTEM is a template DBA account, but SYS (or any user with SYSDBA privileges, which effectively makes them SYS) is more powerful and must be used for some specific commands.

```
connect sys as sysdba;
```

Next, your xepdb2 database is already open in "READ WRITE" mode, so you don't need to open it again.

Last, open your BOOKSHOP database with:

```
alter pluggable database bookshop open;
```

Conceptually, think of pluggable databases the same way you would think of a virtual machine in relation to a bare metal server. It's a logical construct that allows you to consolidate and share certain resources on the database server. The container database (CDB) is somewhat like your hypervisor: you generally don't mess with it except to create pluggable databases (PDBs), or perform certain system-level activities like backup and recovery. All of your application schemas and constructs go in the PDBs.

Comment: Logging in as `sys` did the job. I had to learn about `DROP PLUGGABLE DATABASE bookshop INCLUDING DATAFILES;` to finish the job, and now I can start again. Thanks for your help.